# Python-PPTX Date Axis

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

Is there a way using the python-pptx package to change the base units and major values for a date axis? ie being able to set the X axis for a time series chart to be in years, and to only show every 5th year as a label?

I found this [link](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/cht-date-axis.html?highlight=base%20unit#chart-date-axis) in the docs, but I can't figure out how to set these attributes using python.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That feature is supported by PowerPoint but unfortunately not yet by `python-pptx`.

The `<c:dateAx>` child elements responsible for that behavior are `<c:majorUnit>` and `<c:minorUnit>`. If you can edit the `c:dateAx` subtree to add those (or perhaps just change their attribute values if they already exist) then you might be able to produce the behavior you're after. Note that child element order is significant in PresentationML so you can't just append those elements at the end, you'll need to fit them in at the right place (sequence is specified here: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/master/pptx/oxml/chart/axis.py#L128).